# Insert date programatically in custom module

Tags: nodes, datetime

I am programatically saving values from an array $customer into a content type. The below code works fine and populates the content type customer_profile except for the field date of birth. This field is of type date and date type is set as date only (not date and time). The value in $customer['dob'] is '19/12/1938'. How do I insert this value?

```
$node_data['type'] = 'customer_profile';
$node_data['title'] = $customer['First Name'].' '.$customer['Last Name'];
$node_data['field_customer_gender']['value'] = $customer['Gender'];
$node_data['field_date_of_birth']['value'] = $customer['dob'];
$node = Node::create($node_data);
$node->setPublished(TRUE);
$node->save();
```

Comment: May be this post help you:
https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/204103/inserting-the-value-from-datetime-field-form

Comment: unfortunately it doesnt help! how do I convert the string '19/12/1938' to the drupal date format?

Answer (score 0):

I think correct format is 'yyyy-mm-dd', try to insert '1938-12-19'

Comment: DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', '19/12/1938')->format('Y-m-d'); 
The above works in a normal php script and returns the desired format but when I assign $node_data['field_date_of_birth']['value'] = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', '19/12/1938')->format('Y-m-d'); it doesnt work. I dont understand why

Answer (score 0):

I successfully converted and inserted the date by

```
   $node_data['field_date_of_birth']['value'] = Datetime\DrupalDateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $item['DOB'])->format('Y-m-d')
```