# Instantiate DateTime with localized time

Tags: 8, datetime

I'm trying to migrate some data from MySQL DateTime format. Here's one:

`$old_date = "2019-05-06 08:00:00"`
My content type has a custom field using DateTime.

Using the info from SO links below, I can do this:

`$date_object = DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d H:i:s", $old_date);`

which gives me a lovely object in my current timezone.

`date: 2019-05-06 09:00:00.0 US/Central (-05:00)`

MySQL is looking for a string in the UTC format. When I attempt to format this new object, it dutifully returns

`$date_object->format(DATETIME_DATETIME_STORAGE_FORMAT);`
`"2019-05-06T08:00:00"`

But this is not helpful. Using the Drupal 8.7 admin interface, when I enter the date and time values, I see in MySQL table when I save the node, that I get:

`2019-06-06T03:00:00`

So, apparently Drupal Entity has a handler to automatically instantiate a localized DateTime value in MySQL that is UTC friendly. I ask because I haven't found what this method might be and I have not found it in DrupalDateTime or related classes. Happy to be shown what I've overlooked. Or how to discern how Entity handles all of these functions that I can use in my custom modules.

Or should I do the math for each of these strings and hope I get the correct timezone differential depending on the time of the year?

[How to get formatted date string from a DateTimeItem object](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/252333/how-to-get-formatted-date-string-from-a-datetimeitem-object)

[Inserting the value from Datetime field form](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/204103/inserting-the-value-from-datetime-field-form)

Comment: Before you format in DATETIME_DATETIME_STORAGE_FORMAT you need to set the timezone DATETIME_STORAGE_TIMEZONE, or use the new interface, as explained in the answer to the question you've already linked https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/204107/47547

Comment: How are you doing your migration?  The core Migrate module?  The contrib Feeds module?  Something custom?

Comment: Because of the number of records, opted to do this custom.

Comment: Excellent, @4k4 the new date object must be set to UTC which is what I missed. If you will post it as an answer I will accept.

Comment: OK, I mark it as duplicate so that others can find the correct answer through your high quality question.